# Android:GPS - best way to count kilometers

Tags: android, count, gps, distance

I have one app which count distance in kilometers with GPS.
And my problem is that my app delayed the kilometers.

I use this to update the coordinates.

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 180,1, Loclist);
```

I calculate for 1 meter with 200km\h is take 180 ms.
But maybe this is wrong,because i again get slow distance kilometers.

I don't know what is the best way for updates to travel kilometers with car.

I use this code to calculate the distance.

```
Location locationA = new Location("point A");
    locationA.setLatitude(lastLat);
    locationA.setLongitude(lastLon);


Location locationB = new Location("point B");
        locationB.setLatitude(currentLat);
        locationB.setLongitude(currentLon);


        distanceMeters = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPS chips (and the one in your phone) delivers locations not more than once a second.
So summing up the distances, maybe with a bit of filtering, gives you the correct distance.

of course the distance can be 1-1,5 s delayed, it depends on your app if you want to estiamte the distance drievn since last location update, or if you want to measure only the measured locations.

if you extrapolate then it is clear that later it can turn out that the estimation was wrong( e.g when decelerating the car).

So my advise, you should only sum up what you have alady got from Gps.

Answer (score -1):

speed = lm.getSpeed(); 
if(first_kilometer)
timeTaken =TimeNow - TimeStarted;
else
timeTaken = TimeNow - TimeLastKilometer;

then if you get the 30Km/h..then 30/60 minutes = time taken to get a kilometer.
(speed/60) = timeTakenToGetKilometer;

TimeLastKilometer = TimeNow;

kilometer++;